# Dataflow job template fails for datastream to spanner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-cloud-dataflow, data-stream

Datastream to Spanner Dataflow template fails, followed below doc:

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#datastream-to-cloud-spanner

```
    gcloud beta dataflow flex-template run ora2span1 \
    --project="project-1" \
    --region="us-central1" \
    --template-file-gcs-location="gs://dataflow-templates/latest/flex/Cloud_Datastream_to_Spanner" \
    --parameters \
inputFilePattern="gs://shailesh-ds1/data1/",\
streamName="ora2span1",\
instanceId="quiz-instance",\
databaseId="quiz-database",\
deadLetterQueueDirectory="gs://dataflow-staging-us-central1-664290125703/dlq/"
```

Staging log shows below pattern:

```
{"container_id":"1d9e5ad015e2e03cef94e691be4438b53a70630ff139319b924402f64bf7f381","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/12/23 16:28:39.257154","line":"java_template.go:63","message":"Using launch args: [-cp /template/datastream-to-spanner/*:/template/datastream-to-spanner/libs/*:/template/datastream-to-spanner/classes com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.templates.DataStreamToSpanner --tempLocation=gs://dataflow-staging-us-central1-664290125703/tmp --labels={\n   \"goog-dataflow-provided-template-name\" : \"cloud_datastream_to_spanner\",\n   \"goog-dataflow-provided-template-type\" : \"flex\"\n}\n --serviceAccount=664290125703-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com --streamName=ora2span1 --databaseId=quiz-database --inputFilePattern=gs://shailesh-ds1/data1/ --runner=DataflowRunner --project=shailesh-1 --jobName=daedwedfwedfeadfsedfesd --templateLocation=gs://dataflow-staging-us-central1-664290125703/staging/template_launches/2021-12-23_08_27_41-9888970193837049959/job_object --stagingLocation=gs://dataflow-staging-us-central1-664290125703/staging --region=us-central1 --instanceId=quiz-instance]"}
{"container_id":"1d9e5ad015e2e03cef94e691be4438b53a70630ff139319b924402f64bf7f381","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/12/23 16:28:39.257196","line":"exec.go:38","message":"Executing: java -cp /template/datastream-to-spanner/*:/template/datastream-to-spanner/libs/*:/template/datastream-to-spanner/classes com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.templates.DataStreamToSpanner --tempLocation=gs://dataflow-staging-us-central1-664290125703/tmp --labels={\n   \"goog-dataflow-provided-template-name\" : \"cloud_datastream_to_spanner\",\n   \"goog-dataflow-provided-template-type\" : \"flex\"\n}\n --serviceAccount=664290125703-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com --streamName=ora2span1 --databaseId=quiz-database --inputFilePattern=gs://shailesh-ds1/data1/ --runner=DataflowRunner --project=shailesh-1 --jobName=daedwedfwedfeadfsedfesd --templateLocation=gs://dataflow-staging-us-central1-664290125703/staging/template_launches/2021-12-23_08_27_41-9888970193837049959/job_object --stagingLocation=gs://dataflow-staging-us-central1-664290125703/staging --region=us-central1 --instanceId=quiz-instance"}
{"container_id":"1d9e5ad015e2e03cef94e691be4438b53a70630ff139319b924402f64bf7f381","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/12/23 16:28:39.996145","line":"exec.go:66","message":"log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.templates.DataStreamToSpanner)."}
{"container_id":"1d9e5ad015e2e03cef94e691be4438b53a70630ff139319b924402f64bf7f381","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/12/23 16:28:39.996369","line":"exec.go:66","message":"log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly."}
{"container_id":"1d9e5ad015e2e03cef94e691be4438b53a70630ff139319b924402f64bf7f381","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/12/23 16:28:39.996493","line":"exec.go:66","message":"log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info."}
{"container_id":"1d9e5ad015e2e03cef94e691be4438b53a70630ff139319b924402f64bf7f381","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/12/23 16:28:43.974307","line":"exec.go:66","message":"Exception in thread \"main\" "}
{"container_id":"1d9e5ad015e2e03cef94e691be4438b53a70630ff139319b924402f64bf7f381","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/12/23 16:28:43.978393","line":"exec.go:66","message":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter name must conform to the pattern ^projects/[^/]+/locations/[^/]+/streams/[^/]+$"}
{"container_id":"1d9e5ad015e2e03cef94e691be4438b53a70630ff139319b924402f64bf7f381","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/12/23 16:28:43.978451","line":"exec.go:66","message":"\tat com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:142)"}
{"container_id":"1d9e5ad015e2e03cef94e691be4438b53a70630ff139319b924402f64bf7f381","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/12/23 16:28:43.978467","line":"exec.go:66","message":"\tat com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:47)"}
{"container_id":"1d9e5ad015e2e03cef94e691be4438b53a70630ff139319b924402f64bf7f381","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/12/23 16:28:43.978481","line":"exec.go:66","message":"\tat com.google.api.services.datastream.v1alpha1.DataStream$Projects$Locations$Streams$Get.\u003cinit\u003e(DataStream.java:4875)"}
{"container_id":"1d9e5ad015e2e03cef94e691be4438b53a70630ff139319b924402f64bf7f381","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/12/23 16:28:43.978496","line":"exec.go:66","message":"\tat com.google.api.services.datastream.v1alpha1.DataStream$Projects$Locations$Streams.get(DataStream.java:4835)"}
{"container_id":"1d9e5ad015e2e03cef94e691be4438b53a70630ff139319b924402f64bf7f381","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/12/23 16:28:43.978514","line":"exec.go:66","message":"\tat com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.utils.DataStreamClient.getStream(DataStreamClient.java:190)"}
{"container_id":"1d9e5ad015e2e03cef94e691be4438b53a70630ff139319b924402f64bf7f381","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/12/23 16:28:43.978529","line":"exec.go:66","message":"\tat com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.utils.DataStreamClient.getSourceConnectionProfile(DataStreamClient.java:203)"}
{"container_id":"1d9e5ad015e2e03cef94e691be4438b53a70630ff139319b924402f64bf7f381","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/12/23 16:28:43.978549","line":"exec.go:66","message":"\tat com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.templates.DataStreamToSpanner.getSourceType(DataStreamToSpanner.java:225)"}
{"container_id":"1d9e5ad015e2e03cef94e691be4438b53a70630ff139319b924402f64bf7f381","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/12/23 16:28:43.978565","line":"exec.go:66","message":"\tat com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.templates.DataStreamToSpanner.validateSourceType(DataStreamToSpanner.java:200)"}
{"container_id":"1d9e5ad015e2e03cef94e691be4438b53a70630ff139319b924402f64bf7f381","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/12/23 16:28:43.978580","line":"exec.go:66","message":"\tat com.google.cloud.teleport.v2.templates.DataStreamToSpanner.main(DataStreamToSpanner.java:253)"}
{"container_id":"1d9e5ad015e2e03cef94e691be4438b53a70630ff139319b924402f64bf7f381","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/12/23 16:28:44.002566","line":"exec.go:52","message":"java failed with exit status 1"}
{"container_id":"1d9e5ad015e2e03cef94e691be4438b53a70630ff139319b924402f64bf7f381","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/12/23 16:28:44.002622","line":"launch.go:77","message":"Template launch failed: exit status 1"}
{"container_id":"1d9e5ad015e2e03cef94e691be4438b53a70630ff139319b924402f64bf7f381","severity":"INFO","time":"2021/12/23 16:28:44.002642","line":"launch.go:99","message":"Uploading console logs to gcs location: gs://dataflow-staging-us-central1-664290125703/staging/template_launches/2021-12-23_08_27_41-9888970193837049959/console_logs"}
```

As pre-requisite, target Spanner instance, database and tables already exist. Any idea where it is gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. I would face this issue when I used knid of this API [1] in my code, It seems like some parameter name is incorrect [2], but it's Google-provided template, so you may just try to double-check all of parameter.
2. Please check your Google cloud CLI version is 284.0.0 or later [3].

[1]https://cloud.google.com/datastream/docs/reference/rest/v1alpha1/projects.locations.streams/create

[2] "message":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter name must conform to the pattern ^projects/[^/]+/locations/[^/]+/streams/[^/]+$"

[3]https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#running-the-datastream-to-cloud-spanner-template

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).